# Wifi adapter for raspberry pi zero

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi

I would like to use the raspberry pi zero for a internet of things project but it does not have wifi access by default. I would like to use a usb wifi adapter to connect the pi to the Internet. Here are my must haves:

- be compatible with raspbian
- be under $10

Here are some features that I would like to have but are not required

- have compatibility with 5ghz wifi
- have a microusb connector

I have looked at using a usb wifi adapter with a miniusb to use adapter but that would easily go over $10 and I was wondering if there is anything better.

Comment: What research have you done on this topic so far?

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters
A whole bunch of info on compatible adapters.

Comment: Of curse, nowadays, the correct answer is the [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a coincidence, I've also got a RPi Zero. Check this out on Amazon.com,

"***Edimax EW-7811Un 150Mbps 11n Wi-Fi USB Adapter***"

It's only $8.99. It says it's compatible with RPi and RPi 2. I personally have the wifi dongle that came with the adafruit RPi Zero Starter Pack (which is about $11 w/o shipping).

Hope this is helpful :D